# What is the difference between gql and buildSchema?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, graphql-js, graphql-tag

What is the difference between [graphql-js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) `buildSchema` and the [apollo-server](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server) `gql`? They appear to do a very similar job.

Comment: Did you read the documentation about [gql](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#gql) and [buildSchema](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#buildschema)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly note, apollo-server's `gql` is actually a re-export from [graphql-tag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tag). `graphql-tag` is a ~150 line package who's default and pretty much only useful export is `gql`.

Quick bit of background: the `graphql-js` package provides an official reference implementation of GraphQL in Javascript. It provides two important things basically:

1. The `graphql` function, which will process any GraphQL query against a `GraphQLSchema` object (the GraphQLSchema object is how graphql-js represents your parsed schema).
2. A bunch of utility functions and types for building and validating the `GraphQLSchema` objects used by the `graphql` function from strings.

Now, *this is the part that ultimately confused me*: in `graphql-js`, taking a string and turning it into a `GraphQLSchema` object is a two step process:

- Step 1: String -> AST (done by the `parse` function).
- Step 2: AST -> GraphQLSchema (done by the `buildASTSchema` function).

It is like this is because the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) is useful to a bunch of other tools which aren't even necessarily aware of GraphQL (for example see https://astexplorer.net/), where as the GraphQLSchema is only meaningful to graphql-js and related softwares.

graphql-js exposes the functions for doing both steps and these are reused by downstream implementors (like Apollo). `buildSchema` is just a convenience wrapper to combine these two steps. It's [literally this](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/commit/7e8e57b9d13d82a54ecc72cb176baad0452cd564#diff-2ccb28a3dcd77102a5b18ba56f71ef8a2d7979236a1ef656efeb9b58c48de1a6R511):

```
/**
 * A helper function to build a GraphQLSchema directly from a source
 * document.
 */
export function buildSchema(source: string | Source): GraphQLSchema {
  return buildASTSchema(parse(source));
}
```

The output of `gql` on the other hand is just the AST part, which is the same as the output from the graphql-js `parse` function. `gql` doesn't return a `GraphQLSchema` directly for the reason stated above: the AST is useful (note `gql` is also doing some basic stuff like stateful caching and will merge an array of schema string into a single AST result ...). Eventually the AST will have to be turned into a proper schema though, and apollo-server does this when the server is instantiated (presumably).

To show the relation, we can take the output of `gql` (same as `parse`) run it through `buildASTSchema` (like `buildSchema` does) then pass it to `graphql` and it works the same:

```
import { graphql, buildSchema, buildASTSchema } from 'graphql';
import { gql } from 'apollo-server'; // equivalent to 'import gql from graphql-tag'

const schemaString = `
  type Query {
    hello: String!
  }
`;

const a = buildASTSchema(gql(schemaString));
const b = buildSchema(schemaString);

graphql(a, '{ hello }', { hello: () => 'Hello world!' }).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
graphql(b, '{ hello }', { hello: () => 'Hello world!' }).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

*Gives:*

```
{ data: [Object: null prototype] { hello: 'Hello world!' } }
{ data: [Object: null prototype] { hello: 'Hello world!' } }
```